# Subscribe calls multiple times when creating multiple instances of component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have widgets component which i want to loop , so that i can display data in that component dnamically.

Widgets Component:

```
export class WidgetsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() vId: any;
  charts = {}
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private widgetsService: WidgetsService){}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.vId)
    this.charts[this.vId] = {};
    this.widgetsService.getWidgets(this.vId);

    this.subscription = this.widgetsService.widgetOption.subscribe(option => {
      console.log('component', option); // problem is here (calls multiple times)
      this.charts[this.vId] = option;
      // console.log(this.charts)
    })
    
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

Widgets Service:

```
export class WidgetsService {
  public widgetOption = new Subject<any>();
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){}
  
  getWidgets (id) {
     this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`).subscribe(
      res => {
        // console.log('res', res);
        this.widgetOption.next(res);
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Problem is same data is reflected in UI , because of multiple subscription calls.

If i loop widgets-component two times then subscribe calls 4 times and so on.

How can i avoid such multiple subscribe calls?

**Note:** If i dont loop widgets component then its works fine.

Here is the working demo for the same [stackblitz_demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-app-stack?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwidgets%2Fwidgets.service.ts)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any `Subject` if you want to notify the result of an http call made via the Angular http client.

If you simplify your `getWidgets` method like this

```
  getWidgets (id) {
     return this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
  }
```

you have a method that returns an Observable.

Now you can use this method directly within the `ngOnInit()` method of `WidgetComponents` like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.vId)
    this.charts[this.vId] = {};
    this.widgetsService.getWidgets(this.vId);

    this.subscription = this.widgetsService.getWidgets(this.vId).subscribe(option => {
      console.log('component', option); //calls twice
      this.charts[this.vId] = option;
      // console.log(this.charts)
    })
    
  }
```

So you basically subscribe to the Observable returned by http client and you do not need any Subject to propagate the notification of the result (or error for that matter).

This is [your corrected stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-app-stack-oe4org).

Comment: Thanks Picci for answering,  but i wanted subject there for some reason, because i am doing some extra work there.
My project is huge, so i created simliar functionality for the same to share on stackblitz.

Comment: How can we achieve the same by using subject?

Comment: @SurajGupta If your service is a singleton and you try to keep multiple instance states there, it's obvious you'll run in to problems. You could make a service instance per component instance, put your state in something like ngrx or handle local state within the component, whatever makes more sense to your app.

Comment: Thanks you @alou, i have created multiple instances of my service and it worked.Thanks!!

Comment: Cool :) Maybe you should update your question, suggesting how you solved it for future reference.